# Fixed chunk size S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, multipart

Can I change chunk size to allways be the same ? What I need is fixed chunk size to always be 100mb. I want to send files from browser without passing it throught server. I use signature 4.  It would be cool if we could restrict max file size and max chunk size

Comment: As with your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51211238/1695906) it is unclear what actual problem you are trying to solve, or why.

Comment: I wanted to have control over size of data that i send to s3. If i do it direct from browser I don't have possibiliy to check if part size is the one that I wanted to be. there is no header that will restrict my chunk size. The only way to control size of file is by using `x-amz-decoded-content-length` but it checks on the end, when all chunks are already sended.

Comment: How are you authenticating the requests?

Comment: I use signature v4 to sign each chunk

Comment: Where are you generating the signature, and what kind of credentials are you using?

Comment: I use IAM and I have own server where I generate signature and then with authorization header I send it to s3.